# How to compress a Bitmap when not saved

Tags: android

I am getting picture from a layout and do not want to save it. I want to share it directly through intent `ACTION_SEND` service. when I send it gives exception `Transaction Too many Large: data parcel size 2315980 bytes`

Here is my code snippet

```
View myview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

Bitmap mypicture = getBitmapFromView(myview);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("", mypicture);

intent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you can retain the uri/path used to set the image. then send that uri in your intent instead.

Comment: i don't know how to do that please help me

Answer (score 0):

> I want to share it directly through intent ACTION_SEND service

That is not an option. [`EXTRA_TEXT` holds text](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT). [`EXTRA_STREAM` holds a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM). Neither of those is a `Bitmap`.

> Here is my code snippet

Your extra is pointless, as no `ACTION_SEND` activities will be looking for an extra with an empty key.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your bitmap to a file, then share the uri/link to that file.

```
public static File saveBitmapInternal(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "images");
    if (!imagePath.exists() && !imagePath.mkdirs()) {
        print("Make dir failed");
    }

    return saveBitmap(bitmap, "preview.png", imagePath);
}


private static File saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename, File root) {
    print(String.format("Saving %dx%d bitmap to %s.", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), filename));

    final File file = new File(root, filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 99, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        return file;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        print("Exception!" + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

then to share it,

```
        // Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
                file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share media"));
```

you need to set up the file provider in your manifest (refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). you can create another question if you have queries regarding the fileprovider.

Comment: please help me in making file provider also i am having problems with last parameter of Uri what to pass actually in the last parameter of Uri